# Can we call Mobile phone battery % through USB cable in external device?

Tags: powerquery

I want to call Mobile battery status (how much battery is remaining in mobile phone) through using USB cable can we do this with the help of code?

Comment: Why is this tagged to powerquery?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.